# Is there any option to kill a job running for longer time on remote machine by rundeck itself?

Tags: remote-server, kill-process, rundeck

I need to kill a rundeck job by itself when the job runs more than 2hours on remote machine,is there a possibility

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout value in "Timeout" textbox (When creating or editing your job go to the "Other" tab an see that option, check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYC4s.jpg). You can use values in seconds (like 10s), minutes (like 5m), hours (like 2h), or days (like 2d), also, you can pass an option defined with that value.

I leave a job definition example to test:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='timeout' value='5s' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>13ba3f6b-f921-4ab5-95ba-56eb335eed4b</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HugeDelay</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>name: node01</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <plugins />
    <schedule>
      <month month='*' />
      <time hour='13' minute='19' seconds='0' />
      <weekday day='*' />
      <year year='*' />
    </schedule>
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>sleep 30; echo "hi"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <timeout>${option.timeout}</timeout>
    <uuid>13ba3f6b-f921-4ab5-95ba-56eb335eed4b</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```